# How to Read Configurations from Property File in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

'.properties' files are mainly used to maintain project configuration data, database config or project settings etc. Each parameter in properties file are stored as a pair of strings, in key and value format, where each key is on one line. You can easily read properties from some file using object of type Properties.

Is there a way to Read Configurations from Property File in Cypress? Like in Selenium, we can read properties file, is there a way to do it in Cypress? If so, how?

Comment: This is a vague question. Please add more details like what kind of file you are trying to read from. Add the code you tried. Add errors if you got any.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is possible to read .properties file in cypress?

Comment: Not sure I understood you correctly but this might help you,
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration

Comment: @Nalin In cypress all your configurations are saved in `cypress.json` file.

Comment: Okay so we can read the cypress.json file normally and get all the configuration of the project.

Comment: Whatever configurations you require you can directly add it there and cypress will automatically recognise those configs and apply them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as asking how you can store project-specific variables, not related to the actual configuration of Cypress. If that is true, then there are two fairly simple solutions to storing variables and referencing them in Cypress. (Cypress calls these environment variables)

Option 1: Storing them in `cypress.json`. You'll store them in the `env` object in your `cypress.json`.

```js
{
...
  "env": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
...
}
```

Option 2: Storing them in a separate `cypress.env.json` file. These will just be a JSON file.

```js
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

In both cases, these values can be referenced in code by the following:

```js
Cypress.env('foo');
```

Comment: Can I use 'properties-reader' to read this file in cypress?

Comment: You don't need to use `properties-reader`. Cypress already reads these files and loads them in as Cypress environment variables.  If you need to use one of the variables, you can reference it as `Cypress.env('foo');`

Comment: If you need all environment variables, you can get them as an object using `Cypress.env()` (with no key)